# Как в PyQt5 сделать сохранения?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qsettings, геометрия

Мне нужно чтобы при передвижении картинки и перезаходе в код сохранялись её местоположение.

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("←")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 70px;")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(150, 150)
        self.btn1.move(160, 650)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("→")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 70px;")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(150, 150)
        self.btn2.move(400, 650)

        self.btn3 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn3.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn3.setText("↓")
        self.btn3.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 70px;")
        self.btn3.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn3.resize(150, 150)
        self.btn3.move(280, 790)

        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn4.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn4.setText("↑")
        self.btn4.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 70px;")
        self.btn4.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn4.resize(150, 150)
        self.btn4.move(280, 510)

        self.btn1.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Влево'))
        self.btn1.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вправо'))
        self.btn2.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn3.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вниз'))
        self.btn3.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn4.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вехр'))
        self.btn4.released.connect(self.btn_released)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(500, 500)
        self.lbl1.move(600, 0)

        self.num = 5

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.timer.setInterval(10)

        self.text = None

    def btn_pressed(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.timer.start()

    def btn_released(self):
        self.timer.stop()


    def on_clicked(self):  # , text=''): !!!
        print(f'{self.text}')
        if self.text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x - self.num if x - self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width()
            x = x + self.num \
                if x + self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вниз":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width()
            y = y + self.num \
                if y + self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вехр":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width()
            y = y - self.num \
                if y - self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(2000, 1800)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс [**QSettings**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) обеспечивает постоянные настройки приложения, не зависящие от платформы.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_q1368766.ini'                             # +++


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: pink; 
            border-radius: 35px;
        """)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 30, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.setFixedSize(70, 70)        


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.num = 5
        self.text = None
        
        self.сentralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.сentralWidget.setObjectName("сentralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.сentralWidget)
        
        self.widget_buttons = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget_buttons)
        self.btn4 = PushButton("↑", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn4, 0, 1)
        
        self.btn1 = PushButton("←", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.btn2 = PushButton("→", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 1, 2)
        self.btn3 = PushButton("↓", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn3, 2, 1)
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.сentralWidget) 
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget_buttons, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.btn1.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Влево'))
        self.btn1.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вправо'))
        self.btn2.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn3.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вниз'))
        self.btn3.released.connect(self.btn_released)
        self.btn4.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вехр'))
        self.btn4.released.connect(self.btn_released)

        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.сentralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(200, 200)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.timer.setInterval(10)

        self.load_settings()                                         # +++

    def btn_pressed(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.timer.start()

    def btn_released(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def on_clicked(self):
        if self.text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x - self.num if x - self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width()
            x = x + self.num \
                if x + self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)

        elif self.text == "Вниз":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            h = self.size().height() - self.lbl1.size().height()     # !!!
            y = y + self.num if y + self.num < h else h              # !!!
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)
        elif self.text == "Вехр":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            h = self.size().height() - self.lbl1.size().height()     # !!!
            y = y - self.num if y - self.num > 0 else 0              # !!!
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)   

        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)

        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        self.lbl1.setGeometry(settings.value('RectValue', QRect(0, 0, 200, 200)))
            
    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)   
        settings.setValue('Geometry',    self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())
        settings.setValue('RectValue',  self.lbl1.geometry())
   
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(event)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]